# Java: single class to send AND receive

Tags: java

I'm writing a Selective Repeat program with the specification:

"Implement the sender and the receiver entities in the same class (SRNode) without any loss of generality. Each process of SRNode can perform both sending and receiving."

My understanding of communicating via UDP packets is that you have a Sender/Server class, that focuses only on sending, and a Receiver/Client class, that focuses only on receiving. The receiver blocks while it waits for a message, so how is it possible to create a single entity that can send messages *while blocking* and waiting for messages? I'm guessing this is very possible since it's a requirement for my homework, but perhaps I don't fully understand the sending/receiving functions, even though I've worked with them before. Any help/explanation is appreciated.

Comment: are you allowed to use multiple threads?

Comment: For the topic of your assignment I pressume you're somewhat versed in code. Take a look at [Concurrency and Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Essentialy, you'll have two threads. One listens for new messages while you spawn a new one to send messages when required.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So is this a feasible idea: take my "sender" code and put it in some block of runnable code in SRNode, then take my "receiver" code and put it in some other block of runnable code in SRNode, and have the single class run 2 threads? (I'm not very experienced in multithreading, but I get the basic idea)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your homework is intended to teach you about concurrency and threads.
To avoid doing it for you, perhaps you should read some articles about [concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)